# how to fetch 2 row's data of 1 column into a row in 2 columns

Tags: database, triggers, insert, db2

I have a table

```
create table abc (id integer, value varchar(20), date1 date);
```

data is :

```
insert into abc values (1 , a, '2015-02-01');
insert into abc values (1 , b, '2015-02-02');
insert into abc values (1 , c, '2015-02-03');
```

I want the result like:

```
old value || new value || updated date
a         ||  b        || 2015-02-02
b         || c         || 2015-02-03
```

How do I get this result?

Comment: Your question is not clear. From where do you get the new/old value? Is it something like when a new record is entered update the other table?

Comment: Yes, whenever a record entered in the table with date it will be new record and the previous 1 will be old for the new record.

Comment: You should use triggers in sql to do this. Trigger an insert when an insert occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2's OLAP function can help here:

```
select id,
       lag(value) over (partition by id order by date1) as "old value", 
       value as "new value",
       date1 as "updated date"
 from abc
```

I thought  that you might also need to return the id column as for another id you only need its old and new value.
This query will also return an additional first row which could be helpful as well. If you want to avoid it (as in your example shown) use following SQL

```
with temp as (
select id,
       lag(value) over (partition by id order by date1) as "old value", 
       value as "new value",
       date1 as "updated date"
 from abc)
 select * from temp
  where "old value" is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of sub-select and inner join

```
SELECT 
old.value as "old value",
new.value as "new value",
new.date1 as "updated date"
FROM abc AS OLD
INNER JOIN abc as new
WHERE old.id = new.id
AND new.date1 = ( 
  SELECT MIN(date1) FROM abc
  WHERE old.id = id
  AND date1 > old.date1
)
```

[see SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/397bfb/8/0)